# 1С конфигурация 8.3 почему макет не печатается на всю страницу?

Tags: 1с

Подскажите пожалуйста почему макет не печатается на всю страницу?
Какая то рамка срезает данные макета и переносит на следующую страницу при просмотре и печати. Как ее расширить?
Уменьшила поля со всех сторон, не помогло.
Думала с принтером проблема, но в word такое не происходит.

Почему макет не печатается на всю страницу?
Что это за рамка и как ее расширить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое происходит когда пропорции сформированной страницы/макета не совпадают с пропорциями листа А4. Как вариант установить масштаб по ширине страницы.

Если не поможет и будет выполняться перенос на другой лист, то только подгонять макет.

Comment: жаль что 1с не позволяет точно контролировать процесс печати этого очень не хватает.